# Why are my search results not visible under the search form?

Tags: php, html, search

hoping somebody is able to help!

I have created a search form to enable a user to search for a specific assessment day using the name, date and the company it is for. 
The results of this search should appear below the form used to generate the search. However, at the moment, when the search button is selected the form just refreshes and does not show any results?
Can anyone advise? Code below:

```
    <?php

if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

require_once 'connect.php';



if(isset($_GET['nameofassessmentday'])) {
if(isset($_GET['dateofassessmentday'])) {
if(isset($_GET['companyname'])) {



    $nameofassessmentday = $db-> real_escape_string($_GET['nameofassessmentday']);
    $dateofassessmentday = $db-> real_escape_string($_GET['dateofassessmentday']);
    $companyname = $db-> real_escape_string($_GET['companyname']);

    $query = $db->query ("
        SELECT Name, Company 
        FROM assessment_day_details
        WHERE Name LIKE '{$nameofassessmentday}'
        AND Company LIKE '{$companyname}'
        AND Date_of_Day = '{$dateofassessmentday}'
        ");

        }
    }
}
?>

<div class="result-count">
    Found <?php echo $query->num_rows; ?> results.
</div>

<?php

if($query-> num_rows) {
    while($r = $query->fetch_object())  {
?>      
        <div class="result">
            <a href="#"> <?php echo $r->Name; ?></a>
            <a href="#"> <?php echo $r->Company; ?></a>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Assess Existing Assessment Day-Search</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="style.css">
</head>
<?php

include 'function.php';
}
?>



<body>
    <div id="form">
        <form method="get">
        <p>
        <label>Name of Assessment Day:</label>
            <input type="text" id="nameofassessmentday" name="nameofassessmentday"  required/>
            </p>
        <p>
        <label>Date of Assessment Day:</label>
            <input type="date" id="dateofassessmentday" name="dateofassessmentday" required />
            </p>
        <p>
        <label>Company Name :</label>
            <input type="text" id="companyname" name="companyname"  required/>
            </p>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Search"  />
            </p>

        </form>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Also, just one additional question for future reference. Is there anyway I would be able to hyperlink a search result to go to a particular page?

Thanks in advance!

And as some further information, prior to trying to get the search results to show in the same webpage, I had the below two pages and it worked perfectly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Assess Existing Assessment Day-Search</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="style.css">
</head>
    <?php

    include 'function.php';

    ?>



    <body>
        <div id="form">
            <form action="search.php" method="get">
            <p>
            <label>Name of Assessment Day:</label>
                <input type="text" id="nameofassessmentday" name="nameofassessmentday"  required/>
                </p>
            <p>
            <label>Date of Assessment Day:</label>
                <input type="date" id="dateofassessmentday" name="dateofassessmentday" required />
                </p>
            <p>
            <label>Company Name :</label>
                <input type="text" id="companyname" name="companyname"  required/>
                </p>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Search"  />
                </p>

            </form>
        </div>

    </body>

    </html>

    <?php

require_once 'connect.php'; 
include 'function.php';

if(isset($_GET['nameofassessmentday'])) {
if(isset($_GET['dateofassessmentday'])) {
if(isset($_GET['companyname'])) {



    $nameofassessmentday = $db-> real_escape_string($_GET['nameofassessmentday']);
    $dateofassessmentday = $db-> real_escape_string($_GET['dateofassessmentday']);
    $companyname = $db-> real_escape_string($_GET['companyname']);

    $query = $db->query ("
        SELECT Name, Company 
        FROM assessment_day_details
        WHERE Name LIKE '{$nameofassessmentday}'
        AND Company LIKE '{$companyname}'
        AND Date_of_Day = '{$dateofassessmentday}'
        ");

        }
    }
}
?>

<div class="result-count">
    Found <?php echo $query->num_rows; ?> results.
</div>

<?php

if($query-> num_rows) {
    while($r = $query->fetch_object())  {
?>      
        <div class="result">
            <a href="#"> <?php echo $r->Name; ?></a>
            <a href="#"> <?php echo $r->Company; ?></a>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: `isset($_GET['submit'])` will never evaluate as true, since there's no form element with that `name`.

Comment: top of page : where do $_GET['submit'] come from and did you try to echo it ? if yes, any result ?

Comment: I have now named the submit button to submit and still the form does not show any results, just refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add '%' when you use LIKE in query 
check here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp